# Create one row pivot select using column_names

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

I want make one row select into pivot select which uses column names from db.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT *
FROM COR.PARAMETER_GROUP AS t WHERE  GROUP_CODE = '555' 
UNPIVOT
(
  COLUMN_NAME
  FOR VALUE IN(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PARAMETER_GROUP' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='COR' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC)
) AS u
```

--

```
       COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 COLUMN4 COLUMN5
ROW       1       2       3       4       5
```

=

```
*COLUMN_NAME VALUE*
COLUMN1       1
COLUMN2       2
COLUMN3       3
COLUMN4       4
```

Basicaly i try this but i cant put column names in `FOR`

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this:

```
CREATE TABLE #DataSource
(
    [name] SYSNAME
   ,[pos] INT
);

INSERT INTO #DataSource ([name], [pos])
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
      ,ORDINAL_POSITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = 'PARAMETER_GROUP'
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA='COR';

DECLARE @DynammicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@DynamicPIVOTColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @DynamicPIVOTColumns = STUFF
                          (
                                (
                                SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([name])
                                FROM #DataSource
                                ORDER BY [pos]
                                FOR XML PATH('') ,TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                                ,1
                                ,1
                                ,''
                          );

SET @DynammicTSQLStatement = N'
SELECT *
FROM #DataSource
PIVOT
(
    MAX([pos]) FOR [name] IN (' + @DynamicPIVOTColumns + ')
) PVT';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynammicTSQLStatement;

DROP TABLE #DataSource;
```

I am using dynamic T-SQL statement to build the `PIVOT` statement in order to make it work for each table/view.

Comment: Thanks for reply and effort. What i want to do is create a general select statement which always return one row into a pivot select. What you did is insert ordinal positions of column names. Replace it with row values and thats exacly what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your `dynamic query`.

```
declare  @cols nvarchar(max);
declare  @sql nvarchar(1000);

select @cols =
STUFF((select N',' + QUOTENAME([COLUMN_NAME])
       from (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PARAMETER_GROUP' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='COR') t1
       FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 1, '') + N'';

set @sql = N'select  ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                SELECT cast(ordinal_position as varchar(50)) as ordinal_position
                , column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''PARAMETER_GROUP'' AND TABLE_SCHEMA=''COR''
            ) t1
            pivot 
            (
                max(t1.ordinal_position)
                for t1.column_name in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: edited my question to make it clear. Also thanks for reply